# Number of cores rocket-chip

Tags: riscv

I am operating Linux on top of spike and the rocket-chip. In order to evaluate a program I am trying to get the # of cores configured in spike and the rocket-chip. I already tried to get the information threw proc/cpuinfo with now success. I also wrote a little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int numofcores = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN); 
    printf("Core(s) : %d\n", numofcores);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this program is that it returns 1, which cannot be the correct value, because I configured 2 cores. Is there another possibility to get the # of cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure linux can see both cores? You can check this with something like: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. To support multicore, you will need to turn on SMP support when building riscv-linux.